# how to delete a sql data row c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

The form layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYppQ.png
cbox.text chooses which question.
I have a table(shown below) in my database, I need to allow the user to delete rows using a button.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| tbl_QNS_ID | OptionNumber | OptionLabel |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|          1 |            1 | option1text |
|          1 |            2 | option2text |
|          1 |            3 | option3text |
|          1 |            4 | option4text |
|          1 |            5 | option5text |
|          2 |            1 | option1text |
|         ...|           ...| ...         |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Normally I should be able to use the code below to delete a specific row, but because I have another button on the form that allows the user to add rows as well, I need the button to delete the row with the highest optionnumber.

```
private void btndeleteoption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                string sqlDelete = " Delete from tbl_Option where OptionNumber=1 and tbl_QNS_ID=@qnsid";
                SqlCommand sqldelete = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete);
                sqldelete.Connection = sqlcon;
                sqldelete.parameters.addwithvalue("qnsid",cbox.Text);
                sqldelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    Admin openadmin = new Admin();
                    openadmin.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: What's the error

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: is it the @ in your parameter?
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qnsid", cbox.Text);

Comment: The code below is what I tried, what I need is how to specify the optionnum instead of optionnum=1 because i need the button to delete the row with the highest optionnumber. since the row number could increase due to the add option button that i have on my form

Comment: @mjwills yes, however it will delete all 5 rows of my qnsid=1 if the combobox has question 1 selected.

Comment: What is the value of `cbox.Text`?

Comment: @mjwills i am not sure what you would want me to say, but my cbox has options 1-5(filled by another table) if the user selects 1, it will delete all my rows that contain qns_id=1. I just compiled and it did run.

Comment: @mjwills the code that I have shown is my exact code for my delete button that I have in my project

Answer (score 0):

> is it the @ in your parameter? cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qnsid", cbox.Text); – Imsopov

after i try `@qnsid` and `qnsid` ,both run success

```
void Main()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(this.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string sqlDelete = @" 
        --test data
        CREATE TABLE ##tbl_Option 
            ([OptionNumber] int, [tbl_QNS_ID] int)
        ;

        INSERT INTO ##tbl_Option 
            ([OptionNumber], [tbl_QNS_ID])
        VALUES
            (1, 2)
        ;           
        --sql
        Delete from ##tbl_Option where OptionNumber=1 and tbl_QNS_ID=@qnsid";
        SqlCommand sqldelete = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete);
        sqldelete.Connection = sqlcon;
        sqldelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qnsid", 2);
        sqldelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var results = sqlcon.Query("select * from ##tbl_Option").ToList(); //result null
    }
}
```

Comment: the qnsid part isn't the issue that I am facing though, qnsid works for me but rather the optionnumber specification is the one i need help with.

Comment: follow this [GridView Examples for ASP.NET : Deleting a GridView's Underlying Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972940.aspx)